# Order sort array in angular 7 with multiple states and number

Tags: arrays, json, angular, sorting, angular7

So i need to sort this array in angular 7, i receive this from the api:

```
"Products": [
        {
            "ProductCode": "MC30180",
            "Description": "Description_1",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
            "PendingQuantity": 25,
            "toBeScanned": true
        },{
            "ProductCode": "MC30180",
            "Description": "Description_1",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
            "PendingQuantity": 20,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_2",
            "Description": "Description_2",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0382",
            "PendingQuantity": -1,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_3",
            "Description": "Description_3",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
            "PendingQuantity": 0,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_3",
            "Description": "Description_3",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
            "PendingQuantity": 30,
            "toBeScanned": false
        }
    ]
```

So my code:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        this.data.Products.sort((b, a) => { if (a.PendingQuantity < 0) { return 1; } if (a.PendingQuantity < 0) {return -1; } if (b.PendingQuantity < 0 ) { return 1; } return b.PendingQuantity - a.PendingQuantity });
```

But i need to sort by `PendingQuantity` and `toBeScanned`, but 
before this,

1. i need to sort by negative `PendingQuantity` (negative < 0), also if
   `toBeScanned` is true or false.
2. i need to sort by state `toBeScanned`, before the true and after the
   false, all of this by increased `PendingQuantity`.
3. every `PendingQuantity = 0` must be shown at the end of the array
   list.

I hope i'm being clear.

So the result i would:

```
"Products": [
        {
            "ProductCode": "MC30180",
            "Description": "Description_1",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
            "PendingQuantity": -1,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },{
            "ProductCode": "MC30180",
            "Description": "Description_1",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
            "PendingQuantity": 25,
            "toBeScanned": true
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_2",
            "Description": "Description_2",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0382",
            "PendingQuantity": 20,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_3",
            "Description": "Description_3",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
            "PendingQuantity": 30,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_3",
            "Description": "Description_3",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
            "PendingQuantity": 0,
            "toBeScanned": false
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting an array requires you to compare two elements. In your case, you want an order, given a single element.

What you can do is reduce your array to split it into 4 arrays, given this priority :

1 - Negatives should be first

2 - toBeScanned should be true

3 - Pending at zero should be last

4 - the rest should be sorted

Once reduced, you can then simply concat those arrays to get the expected result.

```js
let products = [
        {
            "ProductCode": "MC30180",
            "Description": "Description_1",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
            "PendingQuantity": 25,
            "toBeScanned": true
        },{
            "ProductCode": "MC30180",
            "Description": "Description_1",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0965",
            "PendingQuantity": 20,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_2",
            "Description": "Description_2",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 0382",
            "PendingQuantity": -1,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_3",
            "Description": "Description_3",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
            "PendingQuantity": 0,
            "toBeScanned": false
        },
        {
            "ProductCode": "Name_3",
            "Description": "Description_3",
            "NationalCode": "N.C. 8913",
            "PendingQuantity": 30,
            "toBeScanned": false
        }
    ];
    
reduced = products.reduce((p, n) => {
  if (n.PendingQuantity < 0) p[0].push(n);
  else if (n.toBeScanned) p[1].push(n);
  else if (!n.PendingQuantity) p[3].push(n);
  else p[2] = [n, ...p[2]].sort((a, b) => a.PendingQuantity - b.PendingQuantity);
  return p;
}, [[], [], [], []]);

sorted = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], reduced);

console.log(sorted);
```